# Wallpaper service is background service/ foreground / system service?

Tags: service, background, system, wallpaper, foreground

Have integrated wallaper service in my app .
Concerns around limitations Android had imposed after Android 8.0.
What could be possible issues as from documemtation things are not clear .

Documentation link is attached for reference -

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background